# Mikoto started at Level 1. Is she a Gemstone or a kid with 'idiosyncracies', or neither?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

According to the [Wiki](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Curriculum_Program#Promotion_and_propaganda), Mikoto was a child prodigy, and started at Level 1 instead of Level 0. Is she a [Gemstone](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone) or a [person with 'idiosyncracies'](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone_Mining#Early_incidents), or neither?

Answer (score 3):

No, she is not.

She has been recognized by the system as someone with high potential, and as such was given funds and research to develop her powers all the way up to level 5. Also, Mikoto's own nature and hard-working personality contributed to her ascent.

Mikoto isn't a gemstone, and wasn't born with any sort of abilities, she got them at Academy City.

Comment: Mmm... True... But how do you "start" at Level 1, without being a Gemstone or something? ... I'm guessing that they measure it after an initial Esperization Process, but that's my fanon. I think...